# Store previous value from stepper in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, uistepper

The logic from here [Stepper value reset after loaded from coredate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395046/stepper-value-reset-after-loaded-from-coredate)  doesn't work with me plus its in obj C.

I have a label and stepper, i need the value in the label to act as a counter almost. Currently, when i close and reopen the views the core data works and the value from before shows in the label, but when i tap the stepper (after coming back to the view with the stepper) the value in the label counts from 0 again, i need it to add on to the previous value!

This must be easy but i can't seem to figure it out!

Thanks for any help in advance

```
@IBAction func stepperTapped(sender: UIStepper) { // when the user taps the stepper

    label.text = String(Int(sender.value)) 
    someObject.theCounterProperty = Int(sender.value)

    do {
        try context!.save()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting the value of the stepper in viewdidload http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805263/can-you-set-a-default-current-value-for-uistepper-object

Comment: Thank you, after thinking about it deeper, you need to set the stepper.value to the label.text in the viewDidLoad func

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the label and the counter are up to date when the view reappears. In `viewWillAppear` set the value from the Core Data object.

```
label.text = String(someObject.theCounterProperty)
counter.value = Double(someObject.theCounterProperty)
```